# How do i solve issue with adding support:design?

Tags: java, android

I need to implement `TextInputLayout` for this i need to add this line in my code

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

and after that i have tryed make a lot of different things to solve it but without success(

Here is my build

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
---> compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile files('libs/svgandroid.jar')
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile files('libs/guava-16.0.1.jar')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
}

// The sample build uses multiple directories to
// keep boilerplate and common code separate from
// the main sample code.
List<String> dirs = [
    'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
    'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
    'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample template process

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        dirs.each { dir ->
            java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
            res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
        }
    }
    androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
}
}
```

Some resources have already been defined and shows the error .. What does it mean?

**What i am doing wrong?**

[image: окно 3]

[image]

Now according to @Pravin answers i solve one issue and it is making a gradle without mistake! but now when i try launch project i have another bug...

[image]

Comment: have you added something  attr.xml

Comment: @Pravin yes, i edited my question...You think it is the reason? But i can't delete it... Maybe i can rename, but i am not sure. I am going to try and make fedback

Comment: @Pravin i have tryed rename this but it still issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using app compat version 23.3.0

Comment: No it doesn't work for me...(( Now according to @Pravin answers i solve one issue and it is making a gradle without mistake but now when i try launch project i have another bug... Which i discribe in editiont my question

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `circularProgress` with this

```
<declare-styleable name="CircularProgress">
        <attr name="borderWidth1" format="dimension" />
 </declare-styleable>
```

and where you have user `borderWidth` for progress use `borderWidth1`

Comment: Also check in your values.xml

Comment: Thanks for your answers i solve one issue and it is making a gradle without mistake but now when i try launch project i have another bug... Which i discribe in editiont my question

Comment: Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try to change your appcompact: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2' to compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0' and build your gradle,
If it's not work, try to clean your project

Comment: No it doesn't work for me...(( Now according to @Pravin answers i solve one issue and it is making a gradle without mistake but now when i try launch project i have another bug... Which i discribe in editiont my question

Comment: ok, that's a good way if the error haved change. Now try to compile this:com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0